# How ignore read only property set during XmlSerializer deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have read only property in my class

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string Amount
{
    get { return "Some value";  }
}
```

When I try deserialize object from file I don't want that deserialization goes throw exception and I don't receive object. I tried use xml ignore attribute but it is not help me. Only what I need to set properties which is exist in my file.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id>1</KaumeheId>
  <PrivaatKey>123</PrivaatKey>
</Class>
```

**Class**

```
public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrivaatKey { get; set; }
    public string Amount
    {
        get { return "Some value"; }
    }
}
```

**Serializer**

```
public static class XmlDeserializerService<T>
{
    public static void LoadDataToClass(T obj, string filePath)
    {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            obj = (T) serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional info(modified):**

If I look in debugger under obj.Amount I have Amount = 'obj.Amount' threw an exception of type `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Have you tried the [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx) class to see if it behaves differently?

Comment: Whar is your exception? your example works with your xml (if you correct Id tag in xml)

Comment: XmlIgnoreAttribute should work as XML will absolutely ignore readonly Property and should create object just from what is defined in XML. More details about exception would be nice.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin if I look in debugger under obj.Amount I have Amount = 'obj.Amount' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your deserialization method, i would change it to return object:

```
public static class XmlDeserializerService<T>
{
    public static T LoadDataToClass(string filePath)
    {    
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return  (T)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

My Class is :

```
public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrivaatKey { get; set; }  
    public string Amount
    {
        get { return "Some value"; }
    }
}
```

If i use it after that :

```
var r = XmlDeserializerService<Class>.LoadDataToClass(@"yourxml");
```

I see all fields:

[image]

That works, if you will have a valid xml, one that you have provided has invalid Id tag. Valid one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <PrivaatKey>123</PrivaatKey>
</Class>
```

Comment: You described half of problem. Another half = provided  XML is not correct. OP should replace this ```<Id>1</KaumeheId>``` by this ```<Id>1</Id>```

Comment: @tym32167 yes, of course, i wrote it already in comments, but you are right, i'll update asnwer

Comment: ah, yes. Sorry, didnt saw it.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin Could you post your class Class?

Comment: @StanislavMachel is the same as yous, i have updated answer

Comment: @MaksimSimkin Thank you I will research this problem, I checked my xml is valid I did error when post question. But I will get some feedback about it, may be it is really not connected with serializer.